# Uncaught Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException: Internal GD font () not available

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use PHP composer to write text in different x and y coordinates. I have downloaded PHP composer and installed `nmcteam/image-with-text` library in my project folder but the problem that I get now is this error says

> Uncaught Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException: Internal GD font () not available.

Also these warnings in the file "Text.php" on the lines 166,182,194

```
     $maxWidthBoundingBox = imagettfbbox($this->size, 0, $this->font, $maxWidthString); //line 166 
       $lineBoundingBox = imagettfbbox($this->size, 0, $this->font, $lineText); // line 182
        $lineBoundingBox = imagettfbbox($this->size, 0, $this->font, $line['text']); // line 194
```

its obvious that there is something wrong with the font but I do not how to solve it

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->font);` return?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this related to Composer?